# Why SQLAlchemy get column names inconsistently in upper/lower case?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2

SQLAlchemy is bringing column names inconsistently, some of them in lower case and others in upper case.  How can I avoid that?  Why is this happening?

Create table ddl is:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."DIM_TRANSACTION"  (
          "TRANSACTION_SK" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
          "JOBNAME" VARCHAR(50 OCTETS) NOT NULL , 
          "TRANSACTION" VARCHAR(50 OCTETS) NOT NULL , 
          "EXEC_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT -1 , 
          "LAST_UPDATE_TS" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP);
```

Code is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine import pandas as pd

conn_string = "db2+ibm_db://myuser:mypassword@myserver:50001/MYDB?Security=SSL" 
db2_engine = create_engine(conn_string)

sql = """
        SELECT TRANSACTION_SK, JOBNAME, TRANSACTION
        FROM TEST.DIM_TRANSACTION
    """

data_df = pd.read_sql(sql, db2_engine)

print(data_df.columns)
```

And the result is

```
Index(['transaction_sk', 'jobname', 'TRANSACTION'], dtype='object')
```

Where two columns are recovered in lowercase and a third one is recovered in uppercase.

Thanks

Comment: If you use `sql = "SELECT * FROM test.dim_transaction"` does `read_sql()` still work? (BTW, for a query you really should be using `read_sql_query()` instead of `read_sql()`.)

Comment: Os the CREATE TABLE statement the one you issued as shown or how was the table created? What are the column names in the system catalog?

Comment: @Gord Thompson:  yes, it works, but with the same behavior. It brings most columns in lowercase but TRANSACTION column in uppercase.  I am suspecting that the reason may be that TRANSACTION is somehow considered a reserved word by SQLALCHEMY

Comment: "I am suspecting that the reason may be that TRANSACTION is somehow considered a reserved word by SQLALCHEMY" - Yes, that's exactly right.